# how to know when devexpress gridview's vertical scroll bar has reached end?

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress, xtragrid

I am using following code to scroll down devexpress grid view

```
pos++;
gridView1.SmoothScroll(pos);
```

I want to know when scrollbar has reached the end

how can I do this ?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps check to see if the last row is visible:

```
if (gridView1.IsRowVisible(gridView1.DataRowCount - 1) == RowVisibleState.Visible) //Do stuff
```

[Check this ticket](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q238860)

Comment: Ah...apologies. I didn't grasp the full extent of the problem then.